# Executing a SQL ALTER TABLE STATEMENT with a variable value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, sql-update, alter-table

I have added a GUID field into my database tables and I want to update existing users by creating a guid value and then storing this for the related fields but I cant seem to execute the statement when I am using a variable, here is my code:

```
--Declaration of Script Variables
DECLARE @companyGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
DECLARE @companyDomain NVARCHAR(256)

SET @companyGUID = NEWID()
SET @companyDomain = 'DOMAIN NAME HERE'

--Company Table Update
ALTER TABLE Company ADD GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT @companyGUID NOT null
ALTER TABLE Company ADD HasCampaignMonitor BIT
ALTER TABLE Company ADD CampaignMonitorListID NVARCHAR(32)
ALTER TABLE Company ADD CampaignMonitorApiKey NVARCHAR(32)
ALTER TABLE Company ADD CampaignMonitorClientID NVARCHAR(32)
ALTER TABLE Company ADD CampaignMonitorIntegratorID NVARCHAR(16)
ALTER TABLE Company ADD CampaignMonitorRedirectUrl NVARCHAR(256)

UPDATE Company SET GUID = @companyGUID where CompanyID = 1
UPDATE Company SET HasCampaignMonitor = 0 where CompanyID = 1

--User Table Update
ALTER TABLE User ADD GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT @companyGUID 
ALTER TABLE User ADD DomainStub NVARCHAR(256) DEFAULT @companyDomain

--Activity Progress Table Update
ALTER TABLE ActivityProgress ADD GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT @companyGUID 

--Answer Table Update
ALTER TABLE Answer ADD GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT @companyGUID
```

Comment: Are you really going to run this script multiple times and needing the `@companyGUID` values to actually be different each time it runs? If not, just generate a Guid once and put it literally in the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use variables in alter statement. The default value is a constraint which can use any static values and some function as the default value.

ALTER TABLE modifies the table's structure and not the stored data.

Alter your tables (possibly with NULL values in the GUID column), Update the new columns, Alter the column with NOT NULL constraint.